# Write selected columns from pandas to excel with xlsxwriter efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I’m trying to write some of the columns of a pandas dataframe to an Excel file, but it’s taking too long. I’m currently using xlsxwriter to write all of the data to the file, which is much faster. How can I write only some of the columns to the file without sacrificing performance?

My code for writing selected columns so far:

```
for col_num, col_name in enumerate(zip(column_indexes, selected_columns)):
for row_num in range(2, max_rows):
    value = df.iloc[row-2][col]
    if pd.isna(value):
        value =''
    worksheet.write(row_num-1, col_num, value )
```

Comment: since you have a pandas dataframe, why aren't you using pd.to_excel with pd.filter (to select the columns you want)?

Comment: I want to change the order and also input other columns in between pandas columns

Comment: Oh, that probably was not me. I have not had a chance to try it out, likely moderators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the write_column method

```
for col_num, col_name in enumerate(selected_columns):
    col_data = df[col_name].tolist()
    worksheet.write_column(1, col_num, col_data)
```

[image]

You can take a look and learn more about here: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html